# PHP : Check value if picture or video or sound

Tags: php, preg-match

I have string variable like this:-

```
$type
```

Some time this variable have value ( images ) :-

```
$type = 'imagename.jpg';
$type = 'imagename.png';
$type = 'imagename.gif';
```

And some time have value ( audio ) :-

```
$type = 'audioname.mp3';
```

And some time have value ( video ):-

```
$type = 'vname.3gp';
$type = 'vname.flv';
$type = 'vname.mp4';
```

Now i need to check this var what type is ( `Images` or `Video` or `Audio` )

How can check it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: `/(images|video|audio)/i` try this...

Comment: @PiotrOlaszewski How does that check the file type?

Comment: @JayBlanchard he want check string in variable.

Comment: Does he @PiotrOlaszewski? The OP says "type" not "string".

Comment: hi , i edit my post, i need to check the string what is type, ( audio , video , images ) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wil echo the type based on the string you defined....

```
$typeArr = explode('.', $type);

switch (end($typeArr)){
 case 'jpg':
 case 'png':
 case 'gif':
   echo 'IMAGE';
   break;
 case 'mp3':
   echo 'AUDIO';
   break;
 case '3gp':
 case 'flv':
 case 'mp4':
   echo 'VIDEO';
   break;
 default:
   echo 'NOT DEFINED';
   break;
}
```